# ffmpeg - Concat multiple video files, add audio, set length to videos combined length

Tags: ffmpeg

I have up until now done this in 2 steps.

1. Concat video files to outputNoAudio.mp4
2. Add audio to outputNoAudio.mp4 trimming with -shortest

Now I'm trying to do this in one step using this line

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i 'vidlist.txt' -i 'music.m4a' -c copy -movflags faststart -y 'test.mp4'
```

If I use    -shortest I end up with an output the length of the shortest video in vidlist.txt. What I'm trying to achieve is the length of all videos combined.

Comment: Your command works here. Share full log.

Comment: @Mulvya it works for me as well. I must have written down the wrong times of the video files before I started testing. I am Sorry for wasting your time. I am new to SO. Should I delete this question, or answer?

Comment: No need to delete. Answer your own question, and mark it as accepted, after a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Mulvya pointed out. The command works with -shortest. I had the times of my test videos wrong when I started testing. Leaving the answer here for for others trying to do the same.

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i 'vidlist.txt' -i 'music.m4a' -c copy -movflags faststart -shortest -y 'test.mp4'
```